# Как достичь такой магии, как это было достигнуто в jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, алгоритм

Как `jQuery` удается реализовать следующие:
Если сделать запрос в виде `$('div')` - он вернет `HTMLCollection` без каких-то дополнительных методов и свойств библиотеки. При этом сохраняет возможность под названием "цепочка вызовов". 
Например, вызов `$('div').css('width',100)` выполнится без проблем. Изначально я думал, что методы "навязываются" на `HTMLCollection`. Но посмотрев, я понял, что ошибся.
Кто знает ответ, пожалуйста напишите фрагмент кода, как это реализовано. Спасибо за внимание

**Дополнение:**

```
var a = function(q){    
     q = document.querySelectorAll(q);  
     console.log('1');  
     return this;  
}  
a.prototype.t = function(){  
   console.log('2');  
   return this;
}  

function _(b){  
   return new a(b);  
}  
_('div').t()
```

Comment: Что значит "_он вернет HTMLCollection без каких-то дополнительных методов и свойств библиотеки_"? Вывожу `console.log($("div").__proto__)` и вижу объект с прототипом JQuery объекта, никаких чистых объектов `HTMLCollection`. Если не так и я что-то не понял, можете собрать тут сниппет?

Comment: В дополнение к вышесказанному и ссылкой на исходник в ответе @Andrew B, обращаю ваше внимание на следующую строку: `init.prototype = jQuery.fn;` и комментарий к ней "// Give the init function the jQuery prototype for later instantiation" в 126,127 строках. Поэтому функции передаются в прототипе, никакой магии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычный `if (проверить что передали) {}` и *method chain*

Про *method chain* простой пример можно посмотреть [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/chain-calls) (нужно нажать **решение**). Смысл в том, что метод/функция возвращает `this`, т.о. вы можете вызывать другие функции/методы того же объекта.

Про магию с определением того, что передали можно [глянуть исходный код](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2-stable/src/core/init.js)

Вот кусочек исходника:

```
// https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2-stable/src/core.js
// Define a local copy of jQuery
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {

    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
}

// https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2-stable/src/core/init.js
jQuery.fn.init = function( selector, context, root ) {
    var match, elem;

    // HANDLE: $(""), $(null), $(undefined), $(false)
    if ( !selector ) {
        return this;
    }

    ...

    // Handle HTML strings
    if ( typeof selector === "string" ) {

        ...

    // HANDLE: $(DOMElement)
    } else if ( selector.nodeType ) {

        ...

    // HANDLE: $(function)
    // Shortcut for document ready
    } else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {

        ...

    }

    if ( selector.selector !== undefined ) {
        this.selector = selector.selector;
        this.context = selector.context;
    }

    ...
};
```

Как видите, простой перебор вариантов, который в некоторых случаях возвращает `this`.

**Добавлено**

Если я правильно понял, Вы хотите добиться подобного результата:

```js
// Создадим функцию, которая возвращает нам новый объект "класса" worker (чтобы самим не писать new - по аналогии с jQ)
var Styler = function(selector) {
  // Т.к. используем new, то у функции worker будет свой this
  return new Styler.worker(selector);
};

// Добавим нашей функции Styler статическое поле worker, в котором будет храниться наш класс
Styler.worker = function(selector) {
  // Назначим экземпляру объекта worker поле elements и сохраним в него список найденных элементов
  this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return this;
}

Styler.worker.prototype.css = function(name, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
    // Т.к. в данный момент мы находимся в экземпляре объекта worker, то используем назначенное в конструкторе значение elements
    this.elements[i].style[name] = value;
  }
  return this;
}

Styler('div').css('color', 'blue');
Styler('div').css('font-size', '26px');
Styler('div').css('font-family', 'Arial').css('font-style', 'italic');
```

```html
<div>Подопытный DIV</div>
<div>Подопытный DIV № 2</div>
```

Comment: Не получается, что-то не доходит до меня. Я вот пример сделал и не получилось сделать, что хотел ( Дополнение в вопросе).

Comment: @Node_pro, не до конца понял вопрос. Ответ дополнен. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, это ли вы имели в виду.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но чуть не в ту сторону. Если вызвать `Styler('div')` - хотел чтобы оно вернуло HTMLCollection, при этом методы `Styler('div').сss()` и другие, какие я задал тоже работали.

Comment: @Node_pro, думаю, так получится сделать только пропатчив `HTMLCollection` и `NodeList`. `$('div')` возвращает не `HTMLCollection`, а объект jquery

Comment: я тоже так считаю, но вот попробуйте вывести в консольке браузера как я сказал и посмотрите =)

Comment: @Node_pro, как я уже написал выше, хоть вы и проигнорировали, там объект jquery. Посмотрите под консолью хрома, что он выдает и можете даже вывести `typeof $('div')`, он выдаст объект. Я подозреваю, что вы не туда смотрите или просто ошиблись.

Comment: @Node_pro, `$('div')` возвращает не HtmlCollection. Напишите как вы смотрели

Comment: Кажется разобрался, спасибо ребята, вот скриншот( yadi.sk/i/tNNLgWz9z32tF), откуда у меня такие мысли появились